# Django: Update model with new foreign_key

Tags: django

I created a form with the model form manager. Before saving my TransactionProfile ModelForm, I want to connect it with an order model. When I print session_order_id it is the correct id, however self.order_set.get is always empty when I print it in the console. Anyone can help me with that? Would you in general solve it the way I did it here, or ist there a more clean method?

In my views.py I have the following:

```
t = transaction_profile.save(commit=False)
t.update_order_with_transaction_profile(session_order_id)
t.save()
```

transactions/models.py

```
class TransactionProfile(models.Model):
    email           = models.EmailField()
    address_line_1  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    update          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer_id     = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def update_order_with_transaction_profile(self, session_order_id):
            # In ModelManager or just in class TransactionProfile
            o = self.order_set.get(order_id=session_order_id)
            o.transaction_profile = self
            o.save()
```

orders/models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id                = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    customer_key            = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    updated                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_profile     = models.ForeignKey(TransactionProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save object to DB before using it as foreign key. Since in your code `t` is not saved in DB, `update_order_with_transaction_profile` will not work.

Instead of `self.order_set`, which gives you only orders related to specific profile(empty list for new object), you can directly query on `Order` model, note you need to save `transaction_profile` firts:

```
t = transaction_profile.save()
t.update_order_with_transaction_profile(session_order_id)

def update_order_with_transaction_profile(self, session_order_id):
        # In ModelManager or just in class TransactionProfile
        o = Order.objects.get(order_id=session_order_id)
        o.transaction_profile = self
        o.save()
```

Comment: Hi @neverwalkaloner thank you for the answer.

I tried the approach, however I am facing one problem. TransactionProfile is a foreign key in the Order model, I can't  import the Order model. I always receive the error ImportError: cannot import name 'Order'.  Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I just tried that, but I receive AttributeError: module 'orders.models' has no attribute 'Model'

Comment: @JonProgrammer oh, sure. Try `from orders import models as order_models` and `order_models.Order.objects.get(order_id=session_order_id)`